# in light of shaffers analysis, what do you think is the best position for and against dualism and materialism?

Tags: mind-body

on shaffers arguments for and against dualism and materialism, what is the best position? and is there a solution to the mind body problem?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a quotation or a summary of the arguments in question?